# How to calculate the sum for each customer ID?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum

I want to create a function that outputs the following for a given dictionary in Python:

```
Date : 20150102
Status : processing

Customer ID 1
- Order 1000000001 => 105.5
- Total => 105.5

Customer ID 2
- Order 100000000111 => 100.5
- Order 10000000011 => 15.5
- Total => 116
```

I have made the exercise except for the **`total`** part. I am simply unable to calculate the **`amount`** for each `customer_id`.

Here is my code:

```
def display(date, status, orders):
    sum_order = 0
    # Print the list of sales:
    for i in orders:
        if (orders[i]['date']) == date:
            if (orders[i]['status']) == status:
                print("Customer ID: ", orders[i]['customer_id'])
                print("- Order {} => {} euros".format(i, orders[i]['amount']))
        sum_order += orders[i]['amount']
        print("total = ", sum_order)


orders = {
'100000000111': {
'status': 'processing',
'customer_id': 2,
'amount': 100.50,
'date': 20150102
},
'1000000001': {
'status': 'processing',
'customer_id': 1,
'amount': 105.50,
'date': 20150102
},
'10000000011': {
'status': 'processing',
'customer_id': 2,
'amount': 15.50,
'date': 20150102
},
};


date = int(input("What date? "))
status = input("Complete or Processing? ")
print(display(date, status, orders))
```

Is it possible to actually solve this problem, and if yes, what would be the solution and why?

Comment: Consider using a dictionary that maps customer id to total amount. Then going through your orders list and updating that total?

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question by deleting the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work fine:

```
def display(date, status, orders):
    sum_order = 0
    temp={}
    # Print the list of sales:
    for k,v in orders.items():

        if(v['date']==date):
            if(v['status']==status):
                if v['customer_id'] in temp:
                    temp[v['customer_id']].append([k,v['amount']])
                else:
                    temp[v['customer_id']]=[[k,v['amount']]]
    for id in sorted(temp):
        print("Customer ID: ", id)
        total=0
        for stuff in temp[id]:
            print("- Order {} => {} euros".format(stuff[0], stuff[1]))
            total+=float(stuff[1])
        print("total = ", total)
    return


orders = {
'100000000111': {
'status': 'processing',
'customer_id': 2,
'amount': 100.50,
'date': 20150102
},
'1000000001': {
'status': 'processing',
'customer_id': 1,
'amount': 105.50,
'date': 20150102
},
'10000000011': {
'status': 'processing',
'customer_id': 2,
'amount': 15.50,
'date': 20150102
},
};


date = int(input("What date? "))
status = input("Complete or Processing? ")

display(date, status, orders)
```

Comment: @Tiramisu By mistake I used `ord` as a variable, it is an in-built function in python, you should consider changing it to some other variable name for eg. `stuff` in my case. Thank You